# Что значит: Inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, generics

Прошу прощения, если вопрос покажется глупым, но почему не компилируется этот код:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Compiled successfully.");
    }

    private static <T extends SomeType> void foo(T genericVar) {
        // ...
        bar(genericVar.getClass(), genericVar);
        // ...
    }

    private static <E extends SomeType> void bar(Class<E> theClass, E instance) {
        // Do something
    }
}

class SomeType {}
```

```html
<!-- Нужно нажать "Выполнить код", чтобы отобразить сниппет (костыли :D)  -->
<script src="//repl.it/embed/G3VH/3.js"></script>
```

При компиляции получается следующее:

```
Main.java:8: error: method bar in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
    bar(genericVar.getClass(), genericVar);
    ^
  required: Class<E>,E
  found: Class<CAP#1>,T
  reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: CAP#1
    lower bounds: T
  where E,T are type-variables:
    E extends SomeType declared in method <E>bar(Class<E>,E)
    T extends SomeType declared in method <T>foo(T)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends SomeType from capture of ? extends SomeType
1 error
```

Вижу, что передаётся неверный второй параметр в функцию bar, но интересно узнать почему так? Ведь по логике типы совместимы, да и с первым параметром не возникает проблем.

Сейчас, чтобы избежать ошибки, изменил тип второго параметра в bar() на SomeType, и это меня устраивает, но хочется понять из-за чего не получается скомпилировать именно так.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getClass()` возвращает тип `Class<? extends T>`

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Compiled successfully.");
  }

  private static <T extends SomeType> void foo(T genericVar) {
    // ...
    bar(genericVar.getClass(), genericVar);
    // ...
  }

  private static <E extends SomeType> void bar(Class<? extends E> theClass, E instance) {
    // Do something
  }
}

class SomeType {}
```

```html
<!-- Нужно нажать "Выполнить код", чтобы отобразить сниппет (костыли :D)  -->
<script src="//repl.it/embed/G3VH/6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А почему <? extends SomeType> != <T extends SomeType>?

Comment: Проблема в аргументах bar, они указывают на один уровень иерархии, к примеру, `(Class<Number>, Number)`, поэтому компилятор не может генерировать подходящие сигнатуры.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.